# create2 opcode in UniswapV2 contract

Tags: uniswap

Here's create2 opcode used by UniswapV2Factory contract

`create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)`

My question is how mload returns the length of creatonCode.
According to my understanding mload is mem[x...x+32] opcode and it returns bytes data

Answer (score 0):

According to the Solidity document "[Layout in Memory](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_memory.html)":

> The length of a dynamic array is stored at the first slot of the array and followed by the array elements.

[image]

Here we have the number "5" at memory 0x80~0x9F, just before the content of the bytes starting at 0xA0.